# Refactoring: Count total lines in all files under a given folder

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, refactoring

I wrote a code to count the number of lines in all the files in a given folder. It works fine, but I am trying to include all the possible C#'s features to refactor it to more compact and efficient code. Please help me do that.

Here is the code.

```
    class LineNumberCounter
{
    public static string Calculate(string folderPath, string pattern = "*.txt")
    {
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath.Trim());
        if (!dirInfo.Exists)
            throw new ArgumentException("No such directory exists");

        StringBuilder returnValue = new StringBuilder();
        long totalLines = 0;

        pattern.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).All(filter =>
        {
            int count = 0;
            dirInfo.GetFiles(filter.Trim(), 
                SearchOption.AllDirectories).All(file =>
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = file.OpenText())
                    {
                        for (; reader.Peek() > -1; count++)
                            reader.ReadLine();
                    }
                    returnValue.AppendLine(string.Format("Number of lines with {0} pattern is {1}",
                        filter, count));
                    totalLines += count;

                    return true;
                }
            );

            return true;
        });

        //foreach (string filter in
        //    pattern.Split(new char[] { ';' },
        //        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        //{
        //    FileInfo[] files = dirInfo.GetFiles(filter.Trim(),
        //        SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        //    int count = 0;
        //    Array.ForEach<FileInfo>(files, file =>
        //    {
        //        using (StreamReader reader = file.OpenText())
        //        {
        //            for (; reader.Peek() > -1; count++)
        //                reader.ReadLine();
        //        }
        //    });

        //    returnValue.AppendLine(string.Format("Number of lines with {0} pattern is {1}",
        //        filter, count));
        //    totalLines += count;
        //}

        returnValue.AppendLine();
        returnValue.AppendLine("Total Lines = " + totalLines);

        return returnValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

Commented lines were the ones I wrote originally. I made some attempt to refactor it. But still want to check if it has any more scope.

Comment: folderPath is not the best approach, I would load sln file since it is text-based and has all included files with the paths inside

Comment: Well the user of the code would not be .Net. It could be any generic Windows folder with any kind of files. The filter/pattern would determine that I am working on the text based file.

Comment: Sln files can be physically in other place on disk, parsing *.sln can be done in any OS I believe. Why would you want to count smth outside sln?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using new `>=.NET 4` method [File.ReadLines()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx)

```
int total = File.GetFiles(folderPath, pattern)
                .Sum(x => File.ReadLines(x).Count());
```

Some considerations from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx):

> The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use
>   ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before
>   the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must
>   wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access
>   the array. Therefore, **when you are working with very large files,
>   ReadLines can be more efficient**.

Comment: Is that it? :o. Wow. Is it that short? Great. Let me check.

Comment: Do File.ReadAllLines store all the text in a string? Because I had a bad experience (well, I were using ruby) with big files that were stock all in my memory, while writing <readline> (count it and forget) / readline (count it and forget) didn't have this problem

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL : right, but since no concrete performance optimization requirements this solution would work pretty fine, each time you are writing short neat code - you have to pay something, the same with LINQ - it is not for free, and the best performance-aware solutions require more technical knowledges so it might be better creating stream and count newline symbols manually

Comment: I think you should use `File.ReadLines` instead of `File.ReadAllLines`. `File.ReadAllLines` will store all the lines in a string array before you can count them, so it's a waste of memory. `File.ReadLines(x).Count()` will count the lines as they are read, without storing them.

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines(x)` will return also an empty lines, which are not *code* lines. This will count the lines count in the file, but not *code* lines count. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Seems elegant, but imho is not so much because, it seems to me, it fills many strings, where you really should just be counting the number of newlines. It feels like the kind of code that makes computers not become faster (in disrespect of moore's law).

Comment: @sll: Yea mine was more a question rather then a complain, thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, pattern(//standard pattern), SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    var count=File.OpenText(filePath).ReadAllLines().Count();
    returnValue.AppendLine(string.Format("Number of lines with {0} pattern is {1}",
            Path.GetExtension(filePath), count));
}
```